# Disable WordPress password reset via mails,instead notify admin about the reset request

Tags: plugins, password

How can I disable password resets via mail and notify the admin via mail about the password reset request the user has made so that he can reset it manually?

So what I'm looking here,the user enters his username/email id in the lost reset form,now here instead of a password reset link being mailed to him,I want the administrator to get an notification email that the user XYZ has requested to reset the password,which the administrator can do it manually after confirming up with the user.

Is there a plugin already that achieve this? I could find lot of plugins that only disable password reset for users.

Answer (score 1):

There is no free plugin on this (or I could not find one).

There are 2 undocumented hooks you need to work:

- **`lost_password`**: Runs before the "retrieve your password by email" form is printed on the login screen.
- **`lostpassword_form`**: Runs at the end of the form used to retrieve a user's password by email, to allow a plugin to supply extra fields.

Anyway, good idea for a new plugin, and I think that only selected administrators should get the emails.